# Angular UI-router - Not populating params despite $stateParams get object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, ui-sref

Im using angular and angular router-ui. I want to make use of dynamic url params.

This is how Im using it:

```
          .state('index.domain', {
            url: '/domain',
            template: "<div ui-view> Home Domain page </div>"
          })

            .state('index.domain.id', {
              url: '/:domainId',
              resolve: {
                domainId: function($stateParams){
                  return $stateParams.domainId;
                }
              },
              templateUrl: "./development/administration/domain.html",
              controller: function(domainId){
                console.log(domainId);
              }
            })
```

Im calling the routing with the following invocation:

```
$state.go('index.domain.id', {"domainId": domainId});
```

It **DOES execute the resolve** and $stateParams get an object with domainId. Despite of that it **does not get into the controller**. The URL/:domainId does not changed either.

**If I change in the browser the URL to point to URL/RANDOM_DOMAIN_ID *(where RANDOM_ID is a domainId valid number)* it executes the resolve and goes to the controller**.

Am I missing something on the $state.go call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vpKHCCYNzwSFGrVqfvXN?p=preview)

I used the above state def as is:

```
.state('index', {
    url: '/index',
    template: "<div ui-view> Index </div>"
  })
.state('index.domain', {
    url: '/domain',
    template: "<div ui-view> Home Domain page </div>"
 }) 
.state('index.domain.id', {
  url: '/:domainId',
  resolve: {
    domainId: function($stateParams){
      return $stateParams.domainId;
    }
  },
  templateUrl: "development/administration/domain.html",
  controller: function(domainId){
    console.log(domainId);
  }
})
```

And made just few adjustments in the calling side - and this is working:

```
<a ui-sref="index.domain.id({domainId: 1})">...
<button ng-click="$state.go('index.domain.id', {domainId: 22});">...
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vpKHCCYNzwSFGrVqfvXN?p=preview)